# How to set the default MenuItem type for a MenuStrip subclass

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I created subclasses of `MenuStrip` and `ToolStripMenuItem` to allow easy localization during runtime.

Right now my classes look like this:

```
public class LocalizedMenuStrip : MenuStrip
{
    public void Localize()
    {
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem Item in Items)
        {
            if (Item is LocalizedMenuItem)
            {
                ((LocalizedMenuItem)Item).Localize();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class LocalizedMenuItem : ToolStripMenuItem
{
    private String textKey;
    private LocalizedString LocalizedText;

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Display")]
    [Description("Sets or returns the TextKey used to retrieve the localized text for this item.")]
    public String TextKey
    {
        get { return textKey; }
        set
        {
            textKey = value;
            LocalizedText = new LocalizedString(value);
            Text = LocalizedText;
        }
    }

    public void Localize()
    {
        Text = LocalizedText;
    }
}
```

This works as i had planned and there is only one thing that is bugging me:

When i add Items to my `LocalizedMenuStrip` using the Designer i always end up getting a standard `ToolStripMenuItem`. Is there a way to tell the designer to create `LocalizedMenuItem`s instead? Maybe by adding an attribute to the `LocalizedMenuStrip`

any help is appreciated

Comment: You'll need to apply the [ToolStripDesignerAvailability] attribute so your custom item class can be selected at design time.  Pretty unclear how you are doing it now.  Making it the *default* selection requires a custom designer for the MenuStrip, that's very little fun.  Cooking your own localization scheme is never not a mistake.

Comment: Right now i simply add a MenuItem and then change its type to my own MenuItemClass. Not much work but it can get tedious.